# Spring Boot EnableJpaRepositories error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am building app with Spring boot and hibernate and after adding repository, I am getting this kind of error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project app: An exception occured while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/scabbard/projects/app/app-back-end/target/classes/com/springapp/app/config/RepositoryConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories.repositoryBaseClass() -> [Help 1]
```

As it looks like the problem is with EnableJpaRepositories, but cant figure out why.

Here is other files:

repository file

```
package com.springapp.app.repository;

import com.springapp.app.entity.PressEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PressRepository extends JpaRepository<PressEntity, Long> {
}
```

Configuration file

```
package com.springapp.app.config;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.springapp.app.repository")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan("com.springapp.app.entity")
public class RepositoryConfig {
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.springapp.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>App</name>

    <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1205-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: First you should remove the dependency hibernate-annotations. This isn't necessary any more and can cause dependency conflicts. Second, i suggest to use the dependency "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" instead of "spring-data-jpa".

Comment: Could you explain me why Hibernate dependencies are not needed, as I guess "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" already has them, but don't understand why?

Comment: hibernate-annotations is not needed. As you can see, the version of hibernate-annotations is 3.5.6, so it is quite old, and not needed any more with newer hibernate versions. "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" will bring in Hibernate as default JPA provider, so you can choose to remove the hibernate-entitymanager dependency or leave it in the POM, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it really helped me resolve my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After changing hibernate dependencies and "spring-data-jpa" with "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" and added "application.properties", it resolved my issue.